# Check if a Moodle user is online

Tags: php, moodle

I need to know if a user is on-line at Moodle, there is a [Moodle block](https://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Online_users_block) for it, but actually it just check if the user had an activity on Moodle in the last X minutes, but in my case that is not useful. There is anyway to know it?

Comment: The web uses HTTP which is a stateless protocol. There is no way to tell precisely if a user is currently online since there is no permanent connection between client and server in a web application. All you can do is check for the last request sent. That is closest you can get.

Comment: Yes, but Moodle record many information on DB (or variables?) that maybe we can infer of check if a user logged out or something?

Comment: Users typically do no log out from a web application. They simply close their browser or their laptop which the server cannot see. There simply is no way to do this. It is against the character of the underlying protocol.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answerers say, it isn't possible to see if a user is currently online. As you mentioned, the online users block checks the value of `mdl_user.lastaccess`. It's probably the best option but even then it depends on the user accessing or refreshing a page. They could be reading a page for 10 minutes for example, so technically still online but it won't show that they are online. Or vice versa, they could have looked at a page and immediately closed it, so it will show they are online but technically not.

Also in my experience, a lot of user's don't log out of Moodle, they just close the page. So its not a reliable way to see if they are currently logged in or not.

For reference, `mdl_user.lastaccess` is updated by the following sequence:

Going to `index.php` or any page that uses `require_login()` which is pretty much most of the pages in Moodle.

This will call `user_accesstime_log()`

If the `mdl_user.lastaccess` time hasn't been updated within the last 60  seconds (set by `LASTACCESS_UPDATE_SECS`) then the `mdl_user.lastaccess` is updated with the current `time()`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I rebuild so many thinks in Moodle that I will create I keepAlive() function, but I appreciate so much your attention!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP doesn't allow you to see who else is online in realtime. You send a request, and get a response back from the server. That's it. Of course, you could send a request and get a response back every second to try to simulate a realtime app, but that gets a little messy.

The best way to get real-time connections is through web sockets, which can be accomplished with a few libraries in node. Just google 'node websocket tutorial' and you'll find what you're looking for.

If you want to outsource the websocket stuff, I highly recommend [pusher.com](http://pusher.com), which only requires that you include some javascript on your webpage to interact with their websocket service.

Of course, if you're trying to get this for Moodle, you may be SOL. But I thought I'd try to explain what you *would* need if you were to do something in real time. Best of luck to you!

Comment: Yes, but Moodle record many information on DB (or variables?) that maybe we can infer or check if a user logged out or something?