# How to find all online userids' in a particular course

Tags: php, moodle

In moodle I can find the logged userid as follows:

```
$userid = $USER->id;
```

How can I find all logged in userids' in a particular course? I have `courseId` with me.

I need to show Logged in usernames in my module.

**moodle version : 2.9.1**

Comment: @davosmith buddy please take a look!!

Comment: Do you mean enrolled in a course? Or currently online? Currently online is pretty much impossible because of the stateless nature of the web - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989872/check-if-a-moodle-user-is-online/32034176#32034176

Comment: @RussellEngland Thanks a lot for the detailed answer link. Cheers!!